# AccessDenied error while connecting AWS S3 using Pentaho

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pentaho, pentaho-data-integration

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1VW7T.png)
Please see the screenshot-
I am new to Pentaho and AWS S3. I am trying to download a file from Amazon S3 using Pentaho but getting the following error:-

```
org.jets3t.service.S3ServiceException: S3 GET failed for '/' XML Error Message:
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Error>
      <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
      <Message>Access Denied</Message>
      <RequestId>XXXXX</RequestId>
      <HostId>XXXXXXX</HostId>
    </Error>
```

I can used the same key to connect the Amazon using Cyberduck, so key is working correct.

Comment: Looks like it is requesting / when it should be requesting a specific file e.g. /myfolder/mydata.csv. Have you configured the data source correctly?

Comment: I tried the same, please the edited screenshot. Still facing the same issue.

Comment: yes. I verified the data source.

Comment: I've experienced issues in pentaho when my amazon secret contained some special characters (like slash, or maybe plus). I've resolved it with generating other secret, which did not contained such characters. Similar issue caused by same library appears in hadoop: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-3733

Answer (score 0):

pentaho might scanning for all the buckets because of /, try providing access to all bucket or mention correct bucket in url. As s3 has case sensitive check for url format and naming conventions.